# Combinatorics and Discrete Mathematics: problems with solutions(set theory, congruences,Recurrence relation...)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, book-recommendation

My final exam of Discrete Mathematics is coming soon, and I need to practice, problem is I can't find good books or pdfs with problems and solutions. 
My exam looks like this:

1. Set theory
2. Mathematical logic(bool algebra etc.) but I know this good so it is not so important
3. Binary Relation(Reflexivity,Symmetry, Transitivity...)
4. Congruences or permutations(usually mod of exponential, or factorials)
5. Recurrence relation
6. Group theory - Binary operators(I hope i translated this ok)

Here is one example of solved exam (It is on croatian!) https://ossunist.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/dm_split_-_rijec5a1eni-pismeni_29-06-2013.pdf

So I would be very grateful if someone know some good books or pdfs with problems and solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not speaking croation, but everything (theory (except the logic part which you don't need that much anyways), exercises, solutions) seems included here:

Elements of Modern Algebra - Linda Gilbert & Jimmie Gilbert

By online reputation it is considered a good text.

Comment: thank you very much, it is little to simple for my needs but it was ok and I passed my exam :)